# How modify input file to add or remove files list before send?

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple code:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" class="form-control-file" @change="onChangeFiles"  multiple="multiple" />

onChangeFiles(event) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      this.files.push(file);
    },
```

i wanna use vue in laravel and only need see files list with able to delete and see new if u want add more to the list. Files should upload to server after click submit button. Is this possible?

Comment: I recommend using filepond if you want that kind of functionality in a file input.

Comment: oo thx i will check